# Selenium WebDriver css selector

Tags: python, css, selenium

```
<div class="card-body">
blah blah
</div>

<div class="card-body">
   <table class="table-striped">
      some a anchor
   </table>
</div>

<div class="card-body">
   <table class="table-striped">
      some a anchor
   </table>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the a anchor (using selenium python) from the third card-body. So I have try this

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card-body:nth-child(3)>table.table-striped a")
```

which does not work

If I use the below,

```
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card-body:nth-child(2)>table.table-striped a")
```

I get all the a anchor from both the 2nd and 3rd instead.

How do I only get the a anchor from the 3rd div.card-body?

Comment: Why not filter using python by accessing the index of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to achieve this using x-path.

```py
driver.find_elements_by_xpath("(//div[@class='card-body'])[2]//a")
```

Comment: this works, though I need to change from 3 to 2 instead.

Comment: I think XPath is currently the only way. [There is no way to select the nth-of-class using this selector.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-of-type#result)

Answer (score 1):

try this XPath:

```
'(//div[@class="card-body"])[3]//a'
```

Answer (score 0):

use `last-of-type`

```
div.card-body:last-of-type a
```

The `:nth-child(n)` selector matches every element that is the nth child, regardless of type, of its parent.

Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: [The :nth-child() CSS pseudo-class matches elements based on their position in a group of siblings.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-child)

Comment: @ChrisWesseling : I was under a different impression, Updated the post.

Comment: Still OP asks for the 3rd. That it's the last, may be a coincidence. nth-of-type is the closest you can come.